# Php query for imploded value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table column where the value is an imploded value like this `5,9,1,6,4,8,2,24,14,3` now I want to run a query possibly like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE /* 1 is in array of  (imploded_table_column)*/`
Please I don't have a clue on how to run such query anyone with an idea or do I have to run the query in a long way like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$val = $sql['imploded_column'];
if(in_array('1', $val)){
    //run code here
}
```

Comment: Please add your problem statement in detail. Question is not clear.

Comment: use `find_in_set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN` or `find_in_set` to solve this problem if you want this as mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 IN (imploded_column);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set(1, imploded_column);
```

OR

You can use `in_array` if you want it as `PHP` solution. Just explode the `$sql['imploded_column']` so it will be an array, after that you can use `in_array`.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$val = explode(",", $sql['imploded_column']);
if(in_array('1', $val)){
    //run code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i think you are looking for `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET($yourValue, column-name)
```

try like below query in this FIND_IN_SET function 2 arguments first value which you want to find second your table column name.

[More about FIND_IN_SET function read here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)